# Conjugate of difference of convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading through [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-097-prediction-machine-learning-and-statistics-spring-2012/projects/MIT15_097S12_proj5.pdf) tutorial on DC programming and the author makes a startling claim without proof:
If $g$ and $h$ are two lower semi-continuous convex function, then the conjugate function of their difference

$$(g-h)^*(y) \equiv \sup\{x'y - (g-h)(x)\} = h^*(y) - g^*(y) $$ where $h^*$ and $g^*$ are their conjugates respectively $g^*(y) \equiv \sup\{x'y - g(x)\}$, etc.

I'm not able to convince myself that this statement is true. Any ideas / suggestions on how its proof might go?

Comment: As we can see from [this link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-097-prediction-machine-learning-and-statistics-spring-2012/projects/), this was a student project, and not something intended to be used as a tutorial for a wide audience. Still, I'll bet the course organizers would be interested to know of the error, if you would consider reaching out to them. They might want to pull the paper from the site.

Comment: That's what I get for trusting the top google search recommendation :)

Comment: I wondered if that's what happened!

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false. In general, the conjugate of $g-h$ is not even finite: e.g., $g\equiv 0$, $h(x)=x^2$.

And when it is finite, the equality has no reason to hold. Let $g(x)=Ax^2$ and $h(x)=Bx^2$ with $A>B>0$. Then $g^*(x)=\frac{1}{4A}x^2$, $h^*(x)=\frac{1}{4B}x^2$, and $(g-h)^*(x)=\frac{1}{4(A-B)}x^2$. Obviously, we should not expect $1/(A-B)$ to be equal to $1/B-1/A$.

The analogous statements for sums and scalar multiples are also false.
The Legendre transform is very nonlinear.